# Save globally unique token which has a short life for website?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, .net-core

I have an API which needs a token to run and other API which returns a token which belongs to me to run first API.
Now I have to save that token somewhere but the problem I have is, that is a single token so I don't need to create a table for it in DB (Also there are hundred thousands of request to DB and I don't want to get the token in every query). And I don't want to save it in `AppSettings.json` as any changes in that file will make my website to restart. And I don't think saving it in the file (e.g. text file) in server is the best practice.
So what is the solution for this?

P.S.: Obviously this token has an expiration date.

Comment: ymmv, but usually redis is ideal for such use-cases, it is fast, designed to serve as a cache, has auto-expiry etc.

Comment: @khachik I checked wiki page of it and it looks promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though your token expires in a short lifetime I still suggest a db table that contains the token & its expiry date (depends how short you really meant though - what are the sensible units to measure it's life in?)

Do not reference the table directly with your request though.

Read the value of the token periodically and cache the value in memory in a singleton or other config object.

Your details may vary depending on:

- how often the token changes (short life means how frequent?)
- whether you can refresh them in advance
- if you can have multiple active tokens at one time
- Security requirements for your token